# How do I set a secret value with build script interaction on team city?

Tags: teamcity

I know I can define a secret value like this in kotlin DSL on teamcity:

```kotlin
params {
  password(
    "env.MY_SECRET_VALUE", 
    "credentialsJSON:faf2d7c8-3565-452a-8cfe-a7a55a4f0f4c", 
    display = ParameterDisplay.HIDDEN
  )
}
```

How do I achieve the same with build script interaction? I mean a command of the kind

```bash
##teamcity[setParameter name='env.MY_SECRET_VALUE' value='1234']
```

Is it possible at all? I was unable to find this use-case [in this documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity), which is the most complete I've found until now on the topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I understand it, making this happen with build script interaction makes no sense, because I'd need to write a command like

```bash
echo "##teamcity[setParameter password='env.MY_SECRET_VALUE' value='1234']"
```

assuming such a command existed. That means TeamCity will display that line in the logs with the value not hidden, making it therefore pointless.